# optimal spatial arrangement (distribution) of plants

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, agriculture

Microalgae are organisms that can grow in aquatic environments and use light and carbon dioxide (CO2) to create biomass. Research showed that Microalgae's biomass can be used as a bio-fertilizer.

My mission is: to find the optimal field patterns . I mean the optimal spatial arrangement (distribution) of plants in a given area. To elaborate more, I need to consider if I plant a given land in raw (strip) pattern or rectangular pattern or maybe hexagonal or circular pattern, can this boost the crop yield or optimize the bio-fertilizer or the water management.

Note: I'm not a biologist, Just a data science student. I'm open to any biology/math resources and any other inspirations or approaches.

Comment: Is your mission to find the optimal pattern or for somebody *else* to find it for you? Also, can you please [edit] your post to clarify your specific question? Thank you.

Comment: yes it is my mission to find the optimal pattern. and my question is exactly : how to find this pattern for a given plant. thank you for your response@theforestecologist

Comment: Do we assume all "leaves" are on a flat surface? I.e., no height/leaves above other leaves.

Comment: we can assume that plants are planted at the same time so we can expect the same growth rate.  So yes we can assume that no height/leaves above other leaves. Sorry for my late response. @BigMistake

Comment: Perhaps the only way to find this out is to try different things and see what works.